# R terra package warp function missing

Tags: r, raster, spatial, gdal

I want to use `warp` function from `terra` package, but it seems the function is not available in my terra library. Is this a bug? Or could it relate to system gdal installation? I have not installed gdal outside R.

Edit: After more workaround I guess function `terra::warp` was in newer version renamed to `terra::resample`. So, there is maybe just inconsistency in help.

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Czech_Czechia.1250  LC_CTYPE=Czech_Czechia.1250    LC_MONETARY=Czech_Czechia.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Czech_Czechia.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] terra_0.8-8   rgdal_1.5-16  landmap_0.0.3 raster_3.3-13 sp_1.4-2     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2   tools_4.0.2      yaml_2.2.1       Rcpp_1.0.5       codetools_0.2-16 grid_4.0.2      
[7] lattice_0.20-41
```

Comment: I don’t see a ‘warp‘ function defined in the terra package documentation. Why do you think such a function exists?

Comment: Based on official pacakge description provided [here](https://rspatial.org/terra/spatial/8-rastermanip.html?highlight=warp#modifying-a-spatraster-object)

Comment: It seem that website is out of sync with the actual package. Looks like the `warp` method is [currently commented out in the source code](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/R/generics.R#L439). The [documentation on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/terra/terra.pdf) will list what's actually in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single `warp` method, terra has `resample` and `project`. With `resample` primarily to transform raster data to another resolution . This is for cases where this cannot be done with (dis)-aggregate --- which would otherwise be preferred. And with `project` primarily for transforming the data to another coordinate reference system.